# How to find the distance from a face of one object to the surface of another object, along the face's normal

Tags: modeling, scripting, faces, normals, bmesh

I feel like this has probably been answered, but I searched and couldn't find an exact solution.

What I want is a quick way to take a selected set of faces on an object (or the vertices that make up the faces), typically ones that are connected along a particular side of a rectangular-shaped object, and move each of them along the face normal until they're a fixed distance away from the surface of whatever object is in that particular direction.

I found an addon that moves faces along the face normal, so I was hoping to add a little bit of code to create a modified addon that would do the job.  OR, maybe there's an easy way to do this already in the Blender interface, and I'm overlooking it.

I created an addon for Blender several years ago, but I'm a little rusty now.  Seems like this should be easy to do, yet my searches have come up empty so far.

Thanks for the help!
-Mike